# Create session in openerp gtk-client 6.0

Tags: python, postgresql, session, odoo

Hi currently i'm using Openerp 6.0 (GTK-Client)

Do you guys have any idea about how to create a session for GTK-Client in openerp 6.0?
The reason of why i want to create is because of i want to ask system rollback the whole process while the connection from client to server was lost.

i already tried some of error handling, such:

- IOError for broken pipe and connection reset
- socket.error
- rpcsession
- etc

but all of them was not working. that's why i was thinking of create a session for GTK-Client.

Do you guys think it is possible to create a session for GTK-Client in openerp 6.0? If not, do you guys have any idea for handled connection lost?

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on this same problem as well, I am working on OpenERP 5.0.10. I have done it on the client side. It worked correctly. The link Below contains the file where I made my modifications.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37021432/rpc.py

Just replace it with your own in clients code. I hope there wont be many differences in 5 and 6's clients versions. I am currently trying it on Server as well. I will post the answer as soon as I am done with it

Comment: Please post code here rather than link to external sites which may be dead in the future.

Comment: Hi Waqar.Thanks for your answer, i just know that you have answered my question. But can you re-upload your file. because currently i can't get that at all.